# Query postgres database from a SQL cell in a .NET Interactive Notebook

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

**Background**: In Visual Studio Code, I can do the following:

1. Install the [.NET Interactive Notebooks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode) extension.
2. `Ctrl-P` `>` `.NET Interactive: Create new blank notebook` `Create as '.dib'`
3. In a *C# (.NET Interactive)* cell, run
   `#r "nuget:Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.SqlServer,*-*"` and
   `#!connect mssql ...`
4. In a *SQL (.NET Interactive)* cell, execute SQL queries against SQL Server.

**Question:** How can I do the same for a Postgres database?

Comment: Looks like were gonna need an extension similar to [Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.SqlServer](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/tree/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.SqlServer) before we can connect that way. Meanwhile, you know you can connect to Postgres directly from Azure Data Studio notebooks, right? We just don't get the polyglot experience that the .NET kernel gives.

Comment: Yes, I use Azure Data Studio now. I find its implementation of notebooks has peculiarities. That's kinda why I'd like to get it working in VS Code.